# Load uiComponent (grid) over ajax request

Tags: magento-2.1

Is there an easy way to call an uiComponent into an ajax response? I created the Controller which returns ResultLayout:

```
public function execute()
{
    $this->initCurrentCustomer();
    $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
    return $resultLayout;
}
```

The layout:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <uiComponent name="ui_grid_name"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```

Which works since i can see the HTML and on ajax request that html is loaded (loader + plus JS for the grid). The uiComponent works on its own (if proper page is created, not ajax request).
And here lies the problem - the JS code doesn't get executed since its a text-return value. Somehow i would need to trigger that but M2 JS is still a bit complexed for me.

Any ideas?